# serialize from post and not able to get data in controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have post data through ajax with serialize method but not able to get data in laravel controller

```
 $scope.submit = function() {
      var data = $('#JobPostStepOne').serialize() + '&step=1';

      $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : baseUrl + "/employer/addJobPost",
          data    : data,
          headers : { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content') }
      }).success(function(data, status) {
          $scope.status = status;
          $scope.data = data;
          $scope.result = data; 
          console.log(result);
      }).error(function(data, status) {
          $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
      });
      return false;
    };
```

post data like this

```
_token=c9fYks8d4vGYZZWtX3MY9DvbqrRVFDu7j3vXF3Ms&jobma_job_post_id=&mode=add&step=1&company_designation=afds&job_type=Permanent&job_description=&company_keywords=&qualification=&min_experience=&max_experience=&salary_type=&job_currency=&min_salary=&max_salary=&salary_negotiable_val=0&job_notice=&step=1


  public function addJobposting(Request $request) {
        dd(Input::get('name'));
        dd ($request->get('name'));
```

it show me null value

Comment: what you get with this code `$request->request` ?

Comment: nothing i am geting

Comment: Means problem in your routing. check that properly

Comment: No page is submit successfully but i am not geting data there

Comment: Parameter 'name' is not sent as a part of POST request.

Comment: Have you try to use `$request->name`?

Comment: try dd($request->all())